# Only in Ubuntu 12.10 Chrome on Youtube, videos are all playing with grain particles all over

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, google-chrome, youtube

It is a clean install of Ubuntu and chrome. Videos play normal on other video sites like DailyMotion. And videos play well on YouTube if I use Firefox.

Chrome version 26.0.1410.43
Ubuntu 12.10 x64

I installed Oracle Java 7 and ubuntu-restricted-extras which, I think, includes latest version of Flash Player.

Comment: Curiously, the ads videos play well with no grain and when the normal videos start to play, the grains come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use google chrome very much, but i have noticed this problem as well on ubuntu 12.04, by googling the problem it seems like disabling PepperFlash plugin is the solution, in order to do this type about:plugins in the adress bar, click on details, search for PepperFlash and disable it. you may need to restart chrome.